# While opening burger menu, my position on the web page jumpes back to to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, menu

I have a little problem. While reading text on the webpage somewhere on the bottom, I push the button on my burger menu and this moves my current position on the webpage to the top. How can I prevent this jump to the top, so I can stay on the same position on the webpage. Note, that I working with default bootstrap 4 menu burger.

[Website link](https://artem404.github.io/shop_test/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? For more try to find the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: https://artem404.github.io/shop_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **Padding** instead of **min-height** to **navbarMain** class

```
.navbarMain{padding: 15px;}
```

instead of

```
.navbarMain{min-height: 70px;}
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, there was a problem with the fact that I fixed <body> position, when opened burger menu, so that my position on the webpage jumped back to the top. Anyway, thanks for response